# How can I find User Stories in TFS which have all related links and child links closed?

Tags: tfs

I managed to get the user stories which have at least one open bug or task but need a way to identify all user stories where all related links and child links are closed. Anyone has an idea?

Here is where I got so far:
[image]

Basically I need a reverse of above. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think TFS Supports this in the UI, you might be able to create something using the WIQL yourself: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/team_foundation/2010/07/02/wiql-syntax-for-link-query/

Comment: And how would I be able to do it? Never used such fnctionality and looks interesting

Comment: No idea, sorry, that's why it's a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linking filters to select Child and Related link types:

[image]

If you want to list user stories which have all linked items closed, you need to use TFS api.

The code snippet below gets all workitems’ ID which linked to a particular workitem, you need to improve the code and check the State field of the linked work items to achieve what you want:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("URL"));
            WorkItemStore workitemstores = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            WorkItem workitem = workitemstores.GetWorkItem(ID);
            if(workitem.Links.Count!=0)
            {
                foreach (Link link in workitem.Links)
                {
                    RelatedLink relatedLink = link as RelatedLink;
                    if (relatedLink != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(relatedLink.RelatedWorkItemId);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, above example is wrong because it will only return user stories with closed children missing out on those which are still open, i.e. those user stories may still be linked to open items so all I want to do is to get only those user stories which have ALL linked items closed

Comment: If you want to list user stories which have all linked items closed, you need to use TFS API. Default UI is unable to give this list.